# Highlighting the nearest edge from mouse pointer in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In `threejs webgl` I want to highlight the nearest edge from my mouse pointer and select it to get the length of the edge.
I am using `Edgesgeometry` to create the edges.

```
var edgeGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(meshes[meshIndex]); // or WireframeGeometry
var edgeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00000, linewidth: 2 });
var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(edgeGeometry, edgeMaterial);

var object = new THREE.Mesh(meshes[meshIndex], material);
object.add(wireframe);
```

Comment: What did you [search for and try so far?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: when i mouseover a face i am able to highlight the edges associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea.

You know which face you're intesecting and you have its edges, you can use `THREE.Line3()`, built from vertices of each edge (thus you'll use `THREE.Line3()` three times). Then, you know the point of intersection and have three lines of `THREE.Line3()`, now you can find the nearest edge by choosing the closest line to the point of intersection, and [`.closestPointToPoint()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Line3.closestPointToPoint) method will help. This method returns the closes point on an edge relatively to the point of intersection.

Means, that you just find three distances from the point of intersection to three edges of the face. And you'll highlight the edge with the minimal distance from it to the point of intersection.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(8, 8).toNonIndexed();
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "blue"
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
scene.add(mesh);

renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];
var localPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
let closestPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
var edgeGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints([
  new THREE.Vector3(),
  new THREE.Vector3()
]);
var edge = new THREE.Line(edgeGeom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
scene.add(edge);

var pos = mesh.geometry.attributes.position;

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(mesh);
  if (intersects.length === 0) return;

  let faceIdx = intersects[0].faceIndex;

  let lines = [
    new THREE.Line3(
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 0),
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 1)
    ),
    new THREE.Line3(
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 1),
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 2)
    ),
    new THREE.Line3(
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 2),
      new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(pos, faceIdx * 3 + 0)
    )
  ];

  let edgeIdx = 0;
  mesh.worldToLocal(localPoint.copy(intersects[0].point));

  let minDistance = 1000;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lines[i].closestPointToPoint(localPoint, true, closestPoint);
    let dist = localPoint.distanceTo(closestPoint);
    if (dist < minDistance) {
      minDistance = dist;
      edgeIdx = i;
    }
  }

  let pStart = mesh.localToWorld(lines[edgeIdx].start);
  let pEnd = mesh.localToWorld(lines[edgeIdx].end);
  edgeGeom.attributes.position.setXYZ(0, pStart.x, pStart.y, pStart.z);
  edgeGeom.attributes.position.setXYZ(1, pEnd.x, pEnd.y, pEnd.z);
  edgeGeom.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;

}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if (intersects.length > 0) {
        intersects[0].object.children[0].material.color.setHex(0xff0000);
        intersectpoint = intersects[0].point;
        var line = new THREE.Line3();
        var positions = intersects[0].object.geometry.attributes.position.array;
        for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 2) {
            line.start.fromArray(positions, i * 3);
            line.end.fromArray(positions, i * 3 + 3);
            var closestPoint = line.closestPointToPoint(intersectpoint);
            distance = closestPoint.distanceTo(intersectpoint);  
        }
    }

Comment: This is what i am doing .its the same thing You suggested but i am stuck here.

Comment: @User123 I've updated the answer with the working example.

Comment: Thanks buddy You saved my day.